# Careers stackoverflow emails

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, email

[image]

Email from careers is misleading. Here is the snapshot.

---

Problem here is contrast in the email description and from email address. From email says do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com and the email body says reply above this line, which is standard way of parsing replies sent via email.

---

> MIME-Version: 1.0 From: "xxxx yyyy (Stack Overflow)"
>    To: xxxx@yyyy.com Reply-To:
>   reply-some-code-here@reply.talent.stackoverflow.com Date: 19 Mar 2019
>   21:29:00 +0000 Subject: some subject Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative;
>   boundary=--boundary_1111_2222222-333333-yyyy-fffff-xxxxx Message-Id:
>
> ----boundary_1111_2222222-333333-yyyy-fffff-xxxxx Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> ```
> Notification
> ```
>
> =20    =20
>           Reply above this line or view on Stack Overflow